# Constant of the double integral in real application

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning

Assume you have the double integral,

$$
\iint f(x,y)dxdy
$$
and want to find the answer by first integrating on $x$ and then integrating on $y$. we know that for each partial integration there is a constant. Now my question is, how to find the constant in the real applications?

I really appreciate if somebody explains that with an example.

Comment: What real application do you have in mind, do you have an example?

Comment: @Winther  unfortunately not. Just want to have an idea.

Comment: First of all double-indefinate integrals do not pop up that often (plus what is explained in the answer below). Also there is not just two free constants of integration: it's often two free functions. For example lets say we wanted to solve $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} = 1$ this way then we would find the solution $f(x,y) = xy + g(x) + h(y)$ where $g,h$ are any differentiable functions.

Comment: @Winther So as far as I realise, there is no answer in the real application of the double integral. Am I right?

Answer (score 5):

The real question is why you would want to calculate an indefinite double integral. If for some really weird reason you wanted to, you would first write a constant for the integration by $x$, and when integrating with respect to $y$ you would integrate this constant and then include a new constant. Something like this is done when finding the potential function of a vector field.

In any "real application" you would not be calculating an indefinite integral (this is a terrible notation and worse name for an antiderivative), so this is a non-issue.

Comment: Very good point on the validity of real world applications and the (largely) nonsensical indefinite integral. FWIW, +1

Comment: Still not clear what we can do in real application